# Django authenticate function return None although the User isn't None

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying to make login with a custom User which using email instead of username, but
authenticate(email=email, password=password)
returns None although the user is exist

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    email    = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] 
    objects = CustomUserManager() # use the custom manager
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Views.py:

```
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class    = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'signup.html' 
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        email     = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password1 = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        password2 = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password2'])
        user      = User(email=email, password=password1, username=email)
        user      = user.save()
        print("User created!")
        user      = authenticate(username=email, password=password1)
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('home')



class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class    =  LoginForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email    = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        print(email, password) # for debugging purposes
        user     = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        print(user) # for debugging purposes
        if user is not None:
            print('do')
            login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(self.request, 'invalid username or password')
            return redirect('login')
```

backends.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, password=None, email=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

```
'accounts.backends.EmailBackend',
```

]

forms.py:

```
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm): 
    email     = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class'      : 'form-control', 
               'type'       : "text",
               'class'      : "form-control",
               'placeholder': "Email"}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(min_length=8, label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'id'         : "password-field",
               'class'      : 'form-control', 
               'type'       : "password",
               'class'      : "form-control",
               'placeholder': "Password",
               'toggle'     : "#password-field",}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(min_length=8, label='Confirm Password', 
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'id'         :"password-field",
               'class'      : 'form-control', 
               'type'       : "password",
               'class'      : "form-control",
               'placeholder': "Confirm Password",}))
    class Meta:
        model  = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class'      : 'form-control', 
               'type'       : "text",
               'class'      : "form-control",
               'placeholder': "Email"}))
    password  = forms.CharField(min_length=8, label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'id'         : "password-field",
               'class'      : 'form-control', 
               'type'       : "password",
               'class'      : "form-control",
               'placeholder': "Password",
               'toggle'     : "#password-field",}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password',)
```

I want to know why the value of user is None. I am sure the email and password matched with database.

Comment: How did you create the given user? The password should be hashed, hence it should *not* match with the one in the database.

Comment: The password in sign up is hashed.
```
        password1 = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        password2 = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password2'])
 ```

Comment: can you share the view(s), and form(s) used to create a user?

Comment: please share the code of make_password() function too.

Comment: I edited the ask and added forms and views

Comment: It does not really make sense to add the solution to your question. It would've been better to just edit my answer to make it 100% correct. Right now it is just confusing to me.

Comment: ok, I will remove it from the solution, I just made this for helping others with the same problem. It didn't occur to me that you could edit your answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your usage of `make_password` and `check_password`.

The `LoginView` should not do `make_password`. This is the function that translates the raw password to the encrypted password. Since you want to store only the encrypted password in your database, you want to use this function when registering a new user **but not** when logging one in.

The function of  [`check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) takes **two** required arguments. This is an error in your code which is not yet encountered.

Your `LoginView` should pass the raw password to your `authenticate` method (right now you are passing the encrypted one). Then in your `authenticate` method you should check the raw password versus the encrypted which comes from the database. These are the two arguments you need to pass to `check_password`.
If you pass the encrypted password to the `check_password` method it will encrypt the encrypted password another time. You will see that `check_password("xyz", "xyz")` **is not** `True`.

```py
class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class    =  LoginForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email    = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']  # pass the raw one
        print(email, password) # for debugging purposes
        user     = authenticate(email=email, password=password) # change username to email here
        print(user) # for debugging purposes
        if user is not None:
            print('do')
            login(self.request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(self.request, 'invalid username or password')
            return redirect('login')
```

```py
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, password=None, email=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password, user.password):  # add pw field to compare
                return user
        return None
```

Comment: Because the [`check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) method encrypts the raw password and compares it to the encrypted database entry. If you pass the encrypted password to the `check_password` method it will encrypt the encrypted password another time. Also linked docs say that you have to pass raw pw and as second parameter the pw field from the database.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I used `user.set_password(password1)` in sign up and in backend.py `if user.check_password(password): # use only password argument`